# Ember computed property from model array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with the property "fees"

```
fees: DS.hasMany('fee')
```

and a fee model with the property "amount"

```
amount: DS.attr('string')
```

in my controller I want a computed property that adds up all of the fee amounts, so I have this

```
feeTotal: Ember.computed('model.fees.@each.amount', function() {
  var total = 0;
  this.get('model').get('fees').forEach(function(fee) {
    total += Number(fee.get('amount'));
  });
  return total;
})
```

This will compute the fee initially, and recompute when a new fee is added, but it doesn't recompute when a fee amount is changed. For example, changing the following input field will update the amount but not the computed total.

```
{{#each model.fees as |fee|}}
  {{input value=fee.amount type="number" placeholder="Fee Amount"}}
{{/each}}
```

Am I missing something in the way the computed property is written?

Comment: does it work if you change DS.attr('string') to DS.attr('number')?

Comment: no, it doesn't change the result. The problem is really that it doesnt recognize a change in the property, regardless of it being a string or number.

Comment: Code looks fine to me, although I saw question here mentioning similar problem after upgrading ember. If you became really desperate you could try ```Ember 2.0```. Only tip I can provide is that you can compute sum and similar things with [reduce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_reduce) and basically make computed function one-liner.

Comment: I've put your code in Ember Twiddle and it seems to work just fine. Maybe you're not displaying `feeTotal` in your template? Computed properties only get calculated when their value is requested, like in a template or using `get()`.

Comment: To clarify here is the code I wrote: https://gist.github.com/jonkoops/063663240a76de9e65a2

Comment: I appreciate the twiddle work, I made it a bit closer to my actual setup, including an upgrade to 2.1.0 - It works in twiddle like a charm but still doesn't happen for me in my project (Yikes). If I find an answer I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'model.fees.length' property to update totalAmount after adding of new fees.

```
Ember.computed('model.fees.length', 'model.fees.@each.amount', function() {...});
```

I have some ideas that you can try:

-bind fee model to your base model with DS.belongsTo()

-save fee after changing its value

```
//template:
<ul>
  {{#each fees as |fee|}}
    <li>
      {{fee.amount}} - {{input type="number" value=fee.amount}} <button {{action 'save' fee}}>Save</button></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

//controller
actions: {
  save(fee) {
    fee.save();
  }
}
```

-watch for 'dirty' values

```
Ember.computed('model.fees.length', 'model.fees.@each.amount', 'model.fees.@each.isDirty', function() {...});
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything but if thats a better way to write it I appreciate it

Comment: Why would any of these things make a difference?

Comment: My base model as a few fees so I have
    fees: DS.hasMany('fee')

Comment: I do save the value after changing it but unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem. I log the fee model after the change and it is up to date, just for some reason the computed property doesnt catch the change =(

Comment: After seeing Jon Koops Ember Trigger example (and updating it to better fit my actual code) I have a feeling something else is happening that doesn't trigger an error in the console but does trip up the computed property or model.